# apply-templates based on attribute id value

Tags: xslt

My XML is as below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <product>
    <admin id="1">
      <name>abc</name>
    </admin>
    <admin id="2">
       <name>kkk</name>
    </admin>
 <product>
```

Here is my XSLT

```
 <xsl:template match="product">
 <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="admin"/>
 </ul>
```

I want to apply templates on "admin" based on attribute id value.

How to apply templates based on attribute value?

---

New question...

If i want to match both admin how to do that. I don't want to use "*" here

```
 <xsl:template match="product">
 <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="admin[@id=1]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="admin[@id=2]"/>
 </ul>
```

Now how to match both?

```
   <xsl:template match="admin">      
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "*based on id value*"? Do you want to apply a template for `<admin>` with a specific id-attribute value?

Comment: Yes. based on id attribute value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you can modify your XSLT with a *predicate*:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="admin[@id = '2']"/>
```

will select only the `<admin>` element with an `id` attribute set to the value `2.`

There are several other predicates you can use to refine the elements selection among them:

1. `<xsl:apply-templates select="admin[@id]"/>` will only retrieve the elements bearing an id attribute, whatever the value;
2. `<xsl:apply-templates select="admin[name/text() = 'abc']"/>` will retrieve the `<admin>` element having a `<name>` child element, which has a text value set to `abc`;
3. `<xsl:apply-templates select="admin[name/text() = 'abc' and not(@id)]"/>` combines two conditions: it will retrieve the `<admin>` element having a `<name>` child element, which has a text value set to `abc`, and has no id attribute.

and so on.

Comment: here i have one more question related to the same. please refer my question above.
Here i want to match them both saparetely and do some action. how to do this

Comment: @user1893874 If the new question is radically different from the original question, it is better to post it as a new question rather than an edit of the existing question.  You can always link to the original question if it makes things clearer.